# For any $A$ and $B$, there must exist some point $z$ with $|g(z)| > A \exp(|z|^B )$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $g$ is a non constant entire function which is bounded on every ray. Show that for any $A$ and $B$, there must exist some point $z$ with $|g(z)| > A \exp(|z|^B )$.